# Erlang exception error: no function clause matching

Tags: erlang

Can you please tell me what's wrong in line 53 of the code?
As i understand it should return {[{12456},{77777}, {99999}, {88888}], []}.
Why is not matching and how to fix it? Thank!

```
fu() ->
Tr = [{12456},{77777}, {99999}, {88888}],
car:foa1(Tr, {[],[]}).

foa1([], Acc) -> Acc;

foa1([{Tr}|Ot], {A1,A2}) ->
Direction = unknown,
A = fun(T, {Acc1, Acc2}) ->
case Direction of
unknown -> {[T | Acc1], Acc2};
_ -> {Acc1, [T | Acc2]}
end
end,
{Acc1, Acc2} =  lists:foldl(A, {[],[]}, Tr),
foa1 (Ot, {A1 ++Acc1,  A2 ++ Acc2}).
```

** exception error: no function clause matching
lists:foldl(#Fun<car.0.18093156>,{[],[]},12456) (lists.erl, line 1262)
in function  car:foa1/2 (car.erl, line 53)

Comment: That's because the 3rd argument of `lists:foldl` expects a list, while in this line `{Acc1, Acc2} =  lists:foldl(A, {[],[]}, Tr),`, `Tr` is NOT a list -> because you do this `foa1([{Tr}|Ot], {A1,A2})`, it makes `Tr` as the element of the first Tuple, i.e. yielding `12456` on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Agus, your comment helped me figure it out !! Everything worked out!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved! I have corrected the format of the list sent to work. Thanks to all